# Spring data jpa datatables: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find entity

Tags: java, spring, datatable, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring jpa datatable in my project:

https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables

A strange thing happened today.
I have the following call in my code:

```sh
DataTablesOutput<Message> messages = datatableMessageRepository.findAll(input, null, spec);
```

It was working fine a couple days ago, the spec is it to limit the result to the specified user.  It stopped working today （as of today, the total records is 23 for all users).

It returns this message:

```sh
DataTables warning: table id=messageTable - javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.mycompany.dao.entity.Message with id 4680
```

The database has record 4680.

I turned on trace, I found this in the log:

```sh
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.390 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] DefaultLoadEventListener - Loading entity: [com.mycompany.dao.entity.Message#4680]
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.392 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] DefaultLoadEventListener - Attempting to resolve: [com.mycompany.dao.entity.Message#4680]
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.397 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] DefaultLoadEventListener - Object not resolved in any cache: [com.mycompany.dao.entity.Message#4680]
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.400 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] AbstractEntityPersister - Fetching entity: [com.mycompany.dao.entity.Message#4680]
```

then a long query, 
and followed by:

```sh
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.599 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4680]
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.603 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader - Bound [2] parameters total
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.827 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering result set [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@d1d2cc5]
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.832 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] ResultSetProcessorImpl - Processing result set
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.836 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] ResultSetProcessorImpl - Done processing result set (0 rows)
[TRACE] 2019-02-11 04:08:56.842 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8000-exec-5] AbstractRowReader - Total objects hydrated: 0
```

But interesting thing is, if I call a MessageRepository.findAll before datatable repository's `findAll` call:

```sh
List<Message> all = mr.findByUser(user);
DataTablesOutput<Message> messages = datatableMessageRepository.findAll(input, null, spec);
```

then the query worked!

So why is that? did I miss config something?

thanks

Comment: show how you implemented datatableMessageRepository.findAll. The standard method has max 2 paras...

Comment: `@Repository
    public interface DatatableMessageRepository extends DataTablesRepository<Message, Long> {

    }`

Comment: So I didn't override anything.  I also have other datatable repositories, most of them just extends the DataTablesRepository and no issues.  So this is really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because JPA always expects a not null value in the column and the entity validation during the load fails. You might have a OneToMany / ManyToOne connected to this column and which causes the entity failing to load as the other end of relationship is not found.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out the problem.  The row has a column which is a foreign key of another table, in db schema, it is set to nullable, but in my entity class, it is set to nullable=false.  Changed to nullable=true and it worked.  But I don't understand why?  Can anyone please explain it to me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue and in my case it caused by relationship between 2 entities.
Fixed by updating `@ManyToOne` annotation *at child entity* to:

```
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ParentEntityClass parent;
```

and, in addition to this `@NotNull` annotation above (*probably not necessary*)